# In nodejs how to read a file and move it to another folder if the file contains a specified text

Tags: node.js

So I have the following code

```
var processed;
fs.readFile(path, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    processed = false;
    //checking if text is in file and setting flag
    processed = true;
});

if (processed == true) {
    try {
        var fname = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
        fs.moveSync(path, './processedxml/' + fname, {
            overwrite: true
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error while moving file to processed folder " + err);
    }

}
```

But I don't get the desired output. Because looks like the readfile is executed by a separate thread and so the value of "processed" is not reliable.

I am not very familiar with nodejs so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: There is also a synchronous version: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options `fs.readFileSync(path, options)`

Comment: Simply move your code into the function rather than setting a flag.

Comment: @Jake while reading the same file it cannot move it

Comment: The `fs.readFile` callback is called after the file is read, not while the file is open, there is likely another issue, perhaps you're trying to move the file to a folder that does not exist.

Comment: @Jake : ohh ok...but how do I get the value of path in the callback

Comment: It looks like you're shadowing the `path` variable. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, your executions are performed by different threads.

In this scenario, you'll need to use promises.

You can solve your need easily by using "**Promise FS**" (you can use any other promise solution anyway).

Your code would be something like the following:

```
fs = require('promise-fs');

var fname = 'test.txt' ;
var toMove = false ;

fs.readFile('test.txt','utf8')
    .then (function (content) {
        if(content.indexOf('is VALID') !== -1) {
            console.log('pattern found!');
            toMove = true ;
        }
        else { toMove = false
        }
        return toMove ;
    }).
    then (function (toMove) {
           if(toMove) {
              var oldPath = 'test.txt'
              var newPath = '/tmp/moved/file.txt'
              fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err
                console.log('Successfully renamed - moved!')
              }) ;
           }
    })
    .catch (function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

Create a file "test.txt" and add the following contents:

```
this is text.file contents
token is VALID
```

The code above will evaluate if "is VALID" is present as content and if it does then it will move the file "test.txt" from your current folder to a new one called "moved" in "/tmp" directory. It will also rename the file as "file.txt" file name.

Hope it helps you.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're shadowing `path`, trying to use it as a variable and as a node module. The easiest way to make this work is to choose a different variable name for the file and move the processing logic into the callback of `fs.readFile`.

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs-extra');

var file = 'some/file/path/foo.xml';
var text = 'search text';

fs.readFile(file, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        //checking if text is in file and setting flag
        if (data.indexOf(text) > -1) {
            try {
                var fname = path.basename(file);
                fs.moveSync(file, './processedxml/' + fname, {
                    overwrite: true
                })
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("Error while moving file to processed folder " + err);
            }
        }
    }
});
```